# Projection of CMIP data

Tags: python, coordinate-system, netcdf, climate

**How to get the spatial projection from NetCDF file in Python? I am working with CMIP6 data.**

Comment: What software/API do you have available? There's a bit of information about coordinate reference systems in NetCDF files https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/3.1/help/data/multidimensional/spatial-reference-for-netcdf-data.htm (it's Esri but there is information that applies to the format in general)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

CMIP6 netCDF data are written using the CF (Climate and Forecast) [conventions](https://cfconventions.org/) according to the "Model Output specifications" [section](https://pcmdi.llnl.gov/CMIP6/Guide/dataUsers.html#2-model-output-specifications) of the CMIP6 Users Guide. How the projection information is stored is described in the [grid mappings section](https://cfconventions.org/Data/cf-conventions/cf-conventions-1.11/cf-conventions.html#grid-mappings-and-projections) of the CF Conventions document.

Besides the ArcGIS support mentioned in a comment above, [GDAL](https://gdal.org/drivers/raster/netcdf.html) and I believe QGIS can read CF/netCDF data.